# call method foreach selected item in a listview

Tags: c#, listview, selecteditem

I want to call a method that takes in a string for each selected item in a listview.

```
foreach (string item in lvwPoliciesAvailableForHoldBack.SelectedItems)
                {
                    Database.HoldBackPolicy(item);
                }
```

I'm running into this error:

Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem' to type 'System.String'.

Here's the "HoldBackPolicy" method:

```
public int HoldBackPolicy(string PolicyNumber)
        {
            int result = 0;

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spHoldBackPolicy", conn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PolicyNumber", PolicyNumber);

            var returnParameter = cmd.Parameters.Add("@RETURN_VALUE", SqlDbType.Int);
            returnParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;

            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                result = Convert.ToInt32(returnParameter.Value);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.Message.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
                conn.Close();
            }
            return result;
        }
```

Comment: well if you have the code... ... ...TRY IT AND FIND OUT.

Comment: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem' to type 'System.String'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't cast a ListViewItem to a string.. the error says it all.

This line:

```
foreach (string item in lvwPoliciesAvailableForHoldBack.SelectedItems)
```

Is wrong. It must be this:

```
foreach (ListViewItem item in lvwPoliciesAvailableForHoldBack.SelectedItems)
```

And this function call, must be this:

```
Database.HoldBackPolicy(item.Text);
```